# Providing Arabic language support to an application

Tags: jquery

I have a chat application . I want to give Arabic language support to my application.
Is there any way to change language when a user selects his language from a select box? The User requires to Write in Arabic in his text area.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Localisation](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html) would be a first step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use unicode chars to code, e.g. \u5234 (or something like that - in java at least).
Also, the user must support right to left keyboard typing if you want to type from right to left in a textbox.